# You see what I am a part of every day, yet you never see me! What am I?

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle, lateral-thinking

You see what I am a part of every day, yet you never see me! What am I?

**Some clues?**
A5: The big, flying GG around me.
B3: Red, yellow, green or blue will all work.
B4: Hit my head too hard :(

*(It's my first puzzle, so I'm open to any suggestions! Good luck!)*

**Hint:**

> On a normal day, you can probably roughly point out where I am, but on certain days (e.g., yesterday (Jun. 24th, 2021)), you can't see me at all!

Comment: Seems like no one has any ideas so far... Shall I add a hint?

Comment: It's usually a good idea to wait at least 24 hours before hinting since there are potential solvers around the world who may not have had a chance to see it yet!

Comment: @SteveV Good point! I guess I'm being too anxious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's

> *The Dark Side of the Moon*, also the title of a Pink Floyd album

Reasons:

> You can see the moon, but obviously never its dark side, because it's unilluminated.* Note: As per Jaap Scherphuis, "The dark side of the moon is a misnomer. The back of the moon is not dark. The only time it is not illuminated at all is during a full moon, and at all other times it is partially illuminated, going through phases just like the front".

A5: The big, flying GG around me.

> "The Great Gig in the Sky" is a song in the album.

B3: Red, yellow, green or blue will all work.

> <s>This is a reference to the album cover, shown below, which features the color spectrum: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/3/3b/Dark_Side_of_the_Moon.png</s> This is a reference to the song "Any Colour You Like" (Thank you, hexomino).

B4: Hit my head too hard :(

> "Brain Damage" is a song in the album.

> And moreover, the clue numbers (A5, B3, B4) are references to specific songs (again, Hexomino discovered this part).

Comment: The clue numbers (A5, B3, B4) seem to all be references to specific songs (track listings on A-side and B-side) so I think B3 might actually be rot13(Nal Pbybhe Lbh Yvxr). Nice solve!

Comment: @hexomino That's right!

Comment: Can you please make a small fix? Rot13(Gur qnex fvqr bs gur zbba vf n zvfabzre. Gur onpx bs gur zbba vf abg qnex. Gur bayl gvzr vg vf abg vyyhzvangrq ng nyy vf qhevat n shyy zbba, naq ng nyy bgure gvzrf vg vf cnegvnyyl vyyhzvangrq, tbvat guebhtu cunfrf whfg yvxr gur sebag.)

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Done!